# Make jQuery .show() to assign display based on Media Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

According to jQuery documentation the .hide() effect stores the element's display value in order to restore it when .show() is called.

> The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ),
>   except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's
>   data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value.
>   If an element has a display value of inline and is hidden then shown,
>   it will once again be displayed inline.

However, I have a navigation UL element that is `display:flex;` when screen width is > 768 and `display:block;` when shown on screens up to 768. So if you are on an iPad vertically, open and close the navigation then rotate to horizontal position, the navigation that should be `display:flex;` is now `display:block;`

BTW I'm using [jquery.slimmenu.js](http://adnantopal.github.io/slimmenu//) from @adnantopal. I tried to override it by adding `.css('display:flex');` depending on `$(window).width()` but Slimmenu's commands prevail.

Comment: If you're using jQuery and have this much control over the CSS, have you considered `.toggleClass()` instead to add and remove a CSS class - something like `.hide-me { display: none; }` - instead of using .show() and .hide()?

Comment: That's a good one but I'm trying to find a workaround overriding jquery.slimmenu before changing its code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript:**

The javascript equivalent of CSS `@media queries` is `window.matchMedia`:

```
var minWidth768px = window.matchMedia("(min-width:768px)");

if (minWidth768px.matches) {
    ....CODE HERE...
    }
```

---

**jQuery:**

The closest jQuery equivalent is `$(window).width()`.

**But...** you need to be aware that `$(window).width()` on its own will *also* include the width of the scrollbar on the right hand side of the window.

So you need to do something like this:

```
$('body, html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
$('body, html').css('overflow', 'auto');
```

Then you can continue in jQuery with:

```
if (windowWidth > 767)  {
        ....CODE HERE...
        }
```